# Working with DST in Rails' ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone and ActiveSupport::TimeZone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, activesupport

I'm having trouble getting DST offsets to matchup between `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` and `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. Let's take Dublin for instance. Dublin is UTC +0 right now and UTC +1 in summer.

First we are generating a select dropdown for users, like so

```
ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.collect{ |tz| ["(GMT#{ActiveSupport::TimeZone.seconds_to_utc_offset(tz.utc_offset)}) #{tz.name}", tz.name] }
```

But this incorrectly shows Dublin as +1. So I adjusted `tz.utc_offset` to `tz.now.utc_offset` and this correctly factors in DST, now showing Dublin as +0.

Great. Well, not quite.

After the user submits a time, we need to adjust that time using the user's selected time zone and then convert it back to UTC. However, when doing this with `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone#change`, like so:

```
> time.change(zone: 'Dublin')
=> Tue, 30 Aug 2022 06:00:00.000000000 IST +01:00
```

This is still treating Dublin as +1, when it should be +0. So my question is, is there a way to factor DST into a `TimeWithZone` object as well, or is there another way I should be going about this?

Comment: On Aug 30, 2022, Dublin *was* using +01:00.  The timestamp being converted is the only one that matters, not the current time.  Also, you might want to review the section on Rails at the bottom of [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint bazinga! can't believe that didn't cross my mind. Thanks for this. Still need to figure out how to build a front-end select that allows the user to see what will be saved by Rails in the back end though...